# Updating a field in a table from a sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a field in a table used in a sub query:

```
UPDATE counsellors_professional_body_link SET membership_number = CONCAT('0', membership_number) WHERE professional_body_link_id IN (SELECT professional_body_link_id FROM counsellors_professional_body_link WHERE professional_bodyid=5 AND CHAR_LENGTH(membership_number) = 5)
```

But I am told:

You can't specify target table 'counsellors_professional_body_link' for update in FROM clause

How best to do this please?

Comment: And update with join, if u add a fiddle, we can help you better, but with this approach, now you can try.

Comment: Thanks I achieved it with a join:

UPDATE (counsellors_professional_body_link AS a) INNER JOIN (counsellors_professional_body_link AS b) ON (a.professional_body_link_id=b.professional_body_link_id AND a.professional_bodyid=5 AND CHAR_LENGTH(a.membership_number) = 5) SET a.membership_number = CONCAT('0', b.membership_number)